# Computing an iterative integer sequence modulo composite n, where the iteration function involves division by a factor of n.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

On page 23 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1029.pdf), the author defines what he calls an "exponential Collatz-like function", $g_4(n)$. (Hereafter I will drop the subscript, as I will not be discussing his other g functions.) g(n) is actually a partial function since it is not defined for $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  The precise definition is rather complex, but it boils down to:$$g(9k+r) = (a_r \times 4^{k} + b_r)/3$$ where $0\le r\lt 9$, $r \not \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $a_r$ and $b_r$ are specified integer constants defined such that the final division by 3 is exact. The author makes a number of claims about how far g(n) can be iterated before becoming $\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, and further iterations are undefined.  Specifically he claims that $g^4(0)$, $g^7(2)$, and $g^{14}(36)$ are all defined, and $\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

My question is how is he able to calculate this?  Clearly not by simulating the Turing machine he's discussing!  Nor by naively iterating the function on a real-world computer; the sequence's power-tower-like growth would rapidly take it out of the range of even a BIGNUM library.

Were it not for that pesky division by three, we could do all the calculations in the ring $\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$.
Of course we can do *one* iteration in that ring.  This would allow us to discover whether the next iteration is defined, and if so, which subformula to use for it.  However, the value we would get for k wouldn't work in that subformula, so we could progress no further.

I *think* we could do 2 iterations in the ring $\Bbb Z/27\Bbb Z$.  Could we do more iterations using a higher power of 3 as the modulus?  And how much higher would it have to be, for each extra iteration gained?  Here my intuition and knowledge of modular arithmetic fail me.

Comment: Since we have almost no information regarding the $a_r$ or the $b_r$ I don't see how you expect us to say much.  Why not write to the author?

Comment: You can get the full definition of g(n) from the linked paper.  However, my idea of working in a ring modulo some high power of 3 - assuming it works at all - should work regardless of the precise value of the $a_r$ and $b_r$.

Answer (score 1):

"Were it not for that pesky division by three, we could do all the calculations in the ring $\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$."

The division by three is easily disposed of.  Just define $h(3n)=3g(n)$, so that $h^j(3n)=3g^j(n)$. Then $$h(27k+3r) = a_r \times 4^k + b_r$$ and we can compute (the residues of) $g^j$ just by computing (them of) $h^j$.

The real problem is the $4^k$.  I had the mistaken idea that if $k \equiv l \pmod m$ then $b^k \equiv b^l \pmod m$, but this isn't the case, so doing the calculations in the ring $\Bbb Z/27\Bbb Z$ won't work.

Still the above does answer the problem I identified, and since the rest of the question is irredeemably wrong-headed, I'm going to mark this one as answered.